# How to store and save data

Tags: vue.js, store

I start to learning store, and i want to upload image, and save it on local. So if i reloaded page image must be saved

store photoUpload.js

```
const state =  {
  photo: '1'
}
const getters = {
  getPhoto: (state) => {
    return state.photo
  }
}
const mutations = {
  setPhoto(state, photoName) {
    state.photo = photoName
  },
}
const actions = {
  getPhoto(context, photo) {
    context.commit('getPhoto', photo)
  }
}
export const testings = {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  mutations,
  getters,
  actions,
};
```

template

```
<div class="upload">
  <img :src="previewImage ? previewImage : 'assets/images/defaultAva.png'" class="profileImg" />
  <label class="edit">
    <input ref="imageInput" type="file" name="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/jpg" @change="uploadImage">
  </label>
</div>

<script>
 data: () => ({
   previewImage: null,
 }),
 computed: {
  getPhoto() {
   return this.$store.getters["photoUpload/getPhoto"];
  },
 },
 methods: {
  uploadImage(e){
   const image = e.target.files[0];
   const reader = new FileReader();
   reader.readAsDataURL(image);
   reader.onload = e =>{
     this.previewImage = e.target.result;
   };
  },
  ...mapActions("testings", ["getPhoto"]),
 },
</script>
```

So in witch way i must to go, i can upload image to previewImage, but how can i send it to store, to save it locally?

Comment: As @RenaudC5  answered, store is basically a container that  holds your application state. But if you want to store your profile in a way that it stay even after reload. You can use webStorage like localStorage or sessionStorage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So if i reloaded page image must be saved

The purpose of the store is to save data betweens components locally to all the application but not on page refresh.

From the [documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/)

> A "store" is basically a container that holds your application state

The most common case is to save data from your api into global variables that can be used in all the application using `getters` as you did.

If you want to keep data on reload you can use other packages like [vuex-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persist).

---

In your case if you want to save image to the store you can just use the actions from the `mapAction`.

Here is how I do it :

```js
methods: {
  uploadImage(e){
   const image = e.target.files[0];
   const reader = new FileReader();
   reader.readAsDataURL(image);
   reader.onload = e =>{
     this.previewImage = e.target.result;
     this.getPhotoToStore(e.target.result) // <-- here 
   };
  },
  ...mapActions({
      getPhotoToStore: "myStore/getPhoto"
  }),
 },
```

And I use the actions as this :

```js
const actions = {
  getPhoto({ commit }, photo) {
    commit('getPhoto', photo) // <-- commiting to the mutations
  }
}
```